# Forcing view to use certain execution plan

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Can I somehow force an execution plan to a view?

I came across to parameter sniffing and I cannot add option recompile to a query because it is generated by DevExpres, so the only option is to change the view

Comment: It could be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47430973/cant-use-db-indexes-with-entity-framework-using-where-clauses

Answer (score 3):

You can't force an execution plan on a view. Depending on how the view is accessed, SQL Server will generate a different plan.

Querying a view without a where clause may result in table scans, but querying the same view with a predicate on AccountID could result in seeks.

It sounds like you might want to research [plan guides](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/plan-guides), which will allow you to supply query hints (including the `USE PLAN` hint) without modifying the incoming query. If you're using SQL Server 2016 or newer, you can also [use Query Store to force a plan](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/erin/plan-forcing-in-sql-server/).